# How to draw shapes in xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin.android

Is there any library or plugin in xamarin.android to allow the user to create shapes like circle and rectangle. I found something like canvasView in android, is there anything like in xamarin.android to make user create a draw, paint.

Answer (score 0):

About creating a draw, paint in xamarin.android, you can consider to use SkiaSharp.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/finger-paint

https://blog.xamarin.com/drawing-with-skiasharp/

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Cherry Bu, I tried them but not able to implement for Android as all the links provided above are for xanarin.forms.